# How to get a random multiple of a given number within a range

Tags: java, random

I'm making a program in which a `JPanel` is created with a random RGB value and the user has to use buttons to match the color in another `JPanel`.

I want the random R, G, and B values to be multiples of 15, though, so the user can match the color more easily.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
int randRed = rand.nextInt(255);
```

and the same for green and blue. I could use a modulus to repeat the code until it happens to be a multiple of 15 but that would be terribly inefficient.

What is the best method to achieve a random multiple of 15 less than 255?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RIght after posting I figured it out...

```
int randRed = (rand.nextInt(17)+1)*15;
```

15 goes into 255 17 times, so just multiple a random int between 0 and 17, add 1, and multiply by 15.

Comment: It should be `(rand.nextInt(17) + 1 ) * 15`

Answer (score 2):

In general,

```
static int randomBoundedMultiple(int bound, int multiplier){
    return new Random().nextInt(bound) * multiplier % bound
}
```

then, in particular,

`randomBoundedMultiple(255, 15);`